# Should I need to repeat on the article "the" "X-ray of the atlas and (the) axis"?

Tags: articles

Should I need to repeat on the article "the" in the sentence

> "X-ray of the atlas and (**the**) axis"?

It's a title that's going to be above the picture.

If someone knows question alike, please let me know and I'll delete the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When two things go together, or when you want two things to be considered together, as atlas and axis, it is common to use one definite article to refer to both of them, as a pair or set. Compare "Picture of the collar and chain." Or "Photo of the kite and string." However, if you wish to emphasize each item, you can use two direct articles, but that would not be as common. So there is no right or wrong; it is up to you.